# How to convert HTML template to php page?

Tags: php

I have a html template with html,css and javascript...can anyone help me in converting this html template to php page.I am a beginner in php so kindly send me some tutorials which explains this conversion

Answer (score 1):

change the format of page to index`.html` to index`.php`

if you write php code on `.php` page :-

```
<?php
//your php code 
?>
```

> Set Up PHP on Your Own PC However, if your server does not support
>   PHP, you must:
>
> install a web server install PHP install a database, such as MySQL The
>   official PHP website (PHP.net) has installation instructions for PHP:
>   http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

[PHP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript can be embedded with each other without any issue.

We can write any HTML, JavaScript or CSS code in PHP.

So, you can rename your `.html` file to `.php`.

And run this PHP on a web server e.g. WAMP server.

Comment: i renamed the .html file to .php and tried running it in a WAMP server. but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just place code inside `<?php ?>` with file extension of `.php`

```
<?php
    #php code 
?>
```

or for now

> Online ***Html to PHP Converter*** [Yellowpipe Internet Services](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/HTML_converter/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension of your file like ***.html to .php*** and put your php code in it as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the format from **.html to .php** inserting `<?php ?>` is not essential it will work fine with out adding it.